# "Failure to find com.aspose:aspose-email:jar:5.3.0.0" when running GroupDocs sample "Java Viewer - Sample Dropwizard"

Tags: aspose-cells, aspose.words, aspose-slides, groupdocs

I'm trying to run this sample "GroupDocs Java Viewer - Sample Dropwizard" 
download it from [here](http://groupdocs.com/Community/files/9/java-libraries/groupdocs_viewer_for_java/category1004.aspx)

it need these jar files:

- aspose-email-5.3.0.0.jar
- aspose-imaging-2.9.0.jar
- aspose-words-15.6.0.jar
- aspose-slides-15.5.1.jar

I can not find them here maven.aspose.com

I found jars with jdk16 but still have the same error:

> Failed to execute goal on project groupdocs-viewer-dropwizard: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.groupdocs.samples:groupdocs-viewer-dropwizard:jar:2.12.0: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.aspose:aspose-email:jar:5.3.0.0,
>   com.aspose:aspose-imaging:jar:2.9.0,
>   com.aspose:aspose-slides:jar:15.5.1,
>   com.aspose:aspose-words:jar:15.6.0: Failure to find
>   com.aspose:aspose-email:jar:5.3.0.0 in
>   http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external was cached
>   in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.external has
>   elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: Is it possible to post the code from a github repo, gist, or pastebin? This allows someone to help answer you without needing to download files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this maven repositories

```
<repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>libs-release</name>
        <url>http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots />
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>libs-snapshot</name>
        <url>http://maven.aspose.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
```

Also you can use Aspose maven page for find any library and get correct code to connect this library [http://maven.aspose.com/repository/webapp/home.html](http://maven.aspose.com/repository/webapp/home.html?0)

For example Aspose.Email you can connect to your project with this code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspose-email</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
    <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
</dependency>
```